# Where should custom "Region" calls be stored?

Tags: civievent, templates, custom-templates

I'm wanting to add content to a region in EventInfo.tpl. The [Docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/region/) give this function as an example, but do not clarify exactly where this "CRM_Core_Region::instance('page-body')->add" method is called from.

```
  CRM_Core_Region::instance('page-body')->add(array(
      'markup' => '<p>Congratulations! You won the lottery!</p>',
  ));
```

Can I call this method from within a theme file like functions.php? Is there a predefined directory where custom region code should live?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement it in hook, if you are looking to add content on event info page than you will need to implement it in pageRun() hook

Comment: Do I need to make an extension that uses the "pageRun" hook or can I declare the hook elsewhere like in my theme's functions.php file?

Comment: You create an extension or use add_filter in your plugin or theme

Answer (score 3):

Solution found:
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/wordpress/

```
add_filter('civicrm_pageRun', 'addJoinLink', 10, 4 );

function addJoinLink() {
    CRM_Core_Region::instance('event-page-eventinfo-actionlinks-top')->add(array(
        'markup' => '<p>Congratulations! You won the lottery!</p>',
    ));
}
```